# How do I get the current size of a matrix stack in OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, matrix

How do I get the current size of a matrix stack (GL_MODELVIEW, GL_PROJECTION, GL_TEXTURE) in OpenGL?

I want this so that I can do some error checking to ensure that in certain parts of the code I can check that the matrix stacks have been left in the original condition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
  GLint depth;
  glGetIntegerv (GL_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH, &depth);
```

The enums for the other stacks are:

```
  GL_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH       
  GL_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH      
  GL_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH
```

If you use multi-texturing, you have more than one texture matrix stack to query. To do so, set the current texture-unit via `glActiveTexture();`.